# Java stopping a thread blocked on input stream read

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream, blocking

From what I understand, once a thread has been started, it can either complete its operation and stop automatically, or if its performing some work in a loop, then Thread.isInterrupted() needs to be checked periodically to determine if it needs to exit the loop.

```
public void run() {

  //initialize input stream
  .....
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len = -1;
  while((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1 && 
 !Thread.isInterrupted()) {
  //write the buffer to some output stream

 }

}
```

But, lets assume that the Thread is stuck in a call to :-

```
public void run() {
//initialize input stream
.....
    InputStream.read(buffer)
    here, buffer = new byte[FILE_SIZE]
    and FILE_SIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024;//100 MB
}
```

Then how can we stop this running thread in this scenario?

Comment: All JDK blocking is interruptible (or at least the NIO stuff is) so all you have to do is [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()).

Comment: There is no guarantee InputStream.read will respond to an interrupt.  Do your reading with a [channel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html) instead of an InputStream to guarantee it.  Or, just let the read finish and check the interrupt status like you’re already doing.  Other threads probably won’t notice the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you know the actual stream type. e.g. in case of `BufferedInputStream` you could use `available()`, to find out how many bytes can be read without being blocked.

Normally to be able to interrupt the thread execution, you should try to read the stream using smaller buffer.
But if you expect that despite the small buffer size the read operation can still block for long, and you want to be able to stop at that point, you can write your code in a way that is prepared for receiving a `Thread.stop()` (e.g. if thread has not stopped 5 seconds after sending `interrupt()` ).

Comment: Thread.stop() has been deprecated since Java 1.1 (or thereabouts)

Comment: @Brian Agnew Exactly. It is deprecated (and not removed) for 8 major 
versions. This might indicate that there is no exact replacement.